# how to compare databases with tables using pandas

Tags: python, mysql, database, pandas, datatable

I am trying to compare different databases and trying to figure out if the tables inside those databases are same/equal. For example I have set it up has follows

Database 'a' has only one table called "abc"
Database 'b' has only one table called "abc"
Database 'c' has two tables called "abc" & "xyz"

I have written the following code and it works fine when executed but as you can see from the output
it says both as "false". But if you see my setup, database 'a' and database 'b' has only one identical Table and i expect it to print "True" BUT it prints "false" and when you compare database 'b' and database 'c', they are not identical because database 'c' has an extra table called 'xyz', so i expect it to print "false" which is correct. 
please let me know what is wrong with my code or if there is work around. Basically i want to do a diff and compare two databases and check to see if they have same identical tables or not?

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
mydb1 = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="xxxxxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxxx", database="a")
mydb2 = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="xxxxxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxxx", database="b")
mydb3 = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="xxxxxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxxx", database="c")
querystmt1 = "SHOW TABLES"
querystmt2 = "SHOW TABLES"
querystmt3 = "SHOW TABLES"
df1 = pd.read_sql(querystmt1, mydb1)
df2 = pd.read_sql(querystmt2, mydb2)
df3 = pd.read_sql(querystmt3, mydb3)
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
print(df1.equals(df2))
print(df2.equals(df3))
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in the values of the dataframes then a solution would be to convert the dataframes to dictionaries and then check if the values are the same:

```py
df1 = pd.read_sql(querystmt1, mydb1)
d1 = df1.to_dict()
df2 = pd.read_sql(querystmt2, mydb2)
d2 = df2.to_dict()
df3 = pd.read_sql(querystmt3, mydb3)
d3 = df3.to_dict()

# Checking
print(list(d1.values()) == list(d2.values()))  # True
print(list(d2.values()) == list(d3.values()))  # False
```

This is not the most computationally efficient way to do it (contains a lot of type conversions) but it's sufficient if it's a one time thing.

If you want to check if the two dataframes contain at least one common value then you may use:

```py
print(any(i in list(d3.values()) for i in list(d2.values())))
# The output is True since 'abc' is a table in both df2 and df3.
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers are possibly different.
Try setting the headers to just indexes before comparing

```
df1.columns = range(df1.shape[1])
df2.columns = range(df2.shape[1])
df3.columns = range(df3.shape[1])
```

Under the assumption that the column order in all dataframes is the same

Answer (score 0):

Try [`pd.testing.assert_frame_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html): It'll return nothing if the two dataframes are equal, and will raise an `AssertionError` if they're not.

It can receive all sorts of keyword arguments to select what to check for in the comparison (e.g. you can pass `check_names=False` if you don't want to check for column names).

It will also be explicit about where are the dataframes not equal; different sizes, different column names, different values - whatever it is, it'll be explicit about it.

Give it a try!